# Is it a conflict of interest to use your dupe hammer to reopen a question you answered?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer, vote-to-reopen, ethics

Is it OK to reopen a question you answered using the dupe-hammer?

On the one hand, the system trusts you because you have earned a lot of upvotes on the topic. On the other hand, the author of the answer has an "incentive" to keep the question open, as it may lead to more readers.

Thoughts?

This is the question that prompted me to ask this: [Floating point comparison with variable in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224581/floating-point-comparison-with-variable-in-bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, yes.

> [conflict of interest](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conflict%20of%20interest)
>
> a conflict between the private interests and the official responsibilities of a person in a position of trust

"Official responsibilities"

> the system trust you as you have earned a lot of upvotes on the topic

"private interests"

> the author of the answer has an "incentive" to keep the question open, as it may lead to more readers.

---

If you're concerned - and you are, you posted this - I'd recommend asking a neutral group/user (like [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), perhaps) for their opinion, and let them handle it.

Comment: "the author of the answer has an "incentive" to keep the question open, as it may lead to more readers" why is this an incentive? If it has an answer, people wouldn't be redirected and would still read their answer (remember that user are lazy, they barely scroll down to read the answer and wouldn't read the banner).